# Unable to set the number of mappers in hadoop on azure

Tags: java, azure, hadoop

I am using the hadoop on azure of Microsoft for running some mapreduce jobs.
I have set the dfs.block.size to 16777216 (i.e. 16MB) and mapred.max.split.size to 16MB.
I have also set the number of map tasks in each task tracker to 16 by going to each of them. 
(it's a 3+1 node cluster).
I also tried setting the mapred.map.tasks property using -D option.
But none of these efforts were successful in increasing the number of map tasks which is surprisingly 1 still..

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance..

EDIT: The input size is huge (in GBs)

Comment: Is the input data you are using splittable? For a quick check try to run the `Teragen` job by providing the desired number of map tasks as described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/12/30/apache-hadoop-on-windows-azure-part-5-running-10gb-sort-hadoop-job-with-teragen-terasort-and-teravalidate-options.aspx .

Comment: Is the input file gzipped (gz file)? And is there just one input file?If yes then as Lorand stated above, it will not be splittable and always will be picked up by a single mapper.

Comment: What do u mean by "have also set the number of map tasks in each task tracker to 16 by going to each of them"? R u changing in the mapred-config.xml file on each node manually? If yes then that's not gonna work. U need to create a mapred-config file and pass the following as bootstrap action while spawning the cluster:
ruby elastic-mapreduce --create --master-instance-type <> --slave-instance-type <> --num-instances 4 --name "MyJob" --bootstrap-action s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/configure-hadoop --args "--mapred-config-file,s3://com.placeiq.data.emr/conf/java-my-mapred-config.xml"

Comment: I m not using a compressed file, all files are images in the input directory in HDFS. It is therefore splittable.

Answer (score 0):

Check, that file is not compressed.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your setting does not work.

you can check running time job configuration accross job conf page, hadoop job conf page is `http://<host>:<port>/jobconf.jsp?jobid=<jobid>`.